# Sql join average

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have two tables to hold orders for products. Order which has a received date and OrderItem which has a price and order id fk.

I have a query that groups orders by date and gets the number of orders for that date, and the total price. I also have a column for the difference in the number of orders from 7 days ago.

However, I also want to be able to get the average of all orders from within the last 7 days.

So at the moment I have the below query:

```
declare @DateFrom datetime
set @DateFrom = '2012-12-01'

declare @DateTo datetime
set @DateTo = '2013-03-13'

;with orders as (
    select 
    cast(o.ReceivedDate as date) as OrderDate, 
    count(oi.Id) as Orders,
    coalesce(sum(oi.Price), 0) as Price
    from OrderItem oi 
    join [Order] o on oi.OrderId = o.Id
    where cast(o.ReceivedDate as date) >= @DateFrom 
    and cast(o.ReceivedDate as date) <= @DateTo
    group by cast(o.ReceivedDate as date)
)

select c1.OrderDate,
c1.Price,
c1.Orders,
c1.Orders - c2.Orders as DIFF7DAYS
from orders c1
left join orders c2 on dateadd(day, -7, c1.OrderDate) = c2.OrderDate
order by c1.OrderDate desc
```

Now I want to add another column which gets the average orders for the last 7 days.

I have tried something like:

```
select c1.OrderDate,
c1.Price,
c1.Orders,
c1.Orders - c2.Orders as DIFF7DAYS,
c3.AverageOrders
from orders c1
left join orders c2 on dateadd(day, -7, c1.OrderDate) = c2.OrderDate
left join (
select OrderDate, avg(Orders) as AverageOrders
from orders
group by OrderDate
) as c3 on c3.OrderDate >= dateadd(day, -7, c1.OrderDate) and c3.OrderDate <= c1.OrderDate     and c3.OrderDate = c1.OrderDate
order by c1.OrderDate desc
```

But doesn't seem to do what I what. I also tried removing the c3.OrderDate = c1.OrderDate from the join but then I get duplicate rows which affects the average. Basically I want add a column to the results that does:

```
select avg(Orders) as AverageOrders
from orders
where OrderDate >= (the current order - 7 days) and OrderDate <= (the current order)
```

But I am not sure how to do this? I have created a sqlfiddle to help explain http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b837/44

So from my sample data what I want to achieve is results like this:

```
|  ORDERDATE | ORDERS | PRICE |  DIFF7DAYS  | AVERAGE |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-01-25 |      7 |    38 |           6 |       2 |
| 2013-01-24 |      2 |    12 |        null |       1 |
| 2013-01-23 |      1 |    10 |        null |       1 |
| 2013-01-22 |      1 |    33 |        null |
| 2013-01-18 |      1 |    10 |        null |
| 2013-01-10 |      1 |     3 |          -2 |
| 2013-01-08 |      2 |    11 |        null |
| 2013-01-04 |      1 |     1 |        null |
| 2013-01-03 |      3 |    46 |        null |
```

As you can see, the 25th has an average of 2 because the last 7 days (25, 24, 23, 22, 18) has a rounded average of 2.

I also want to be able to extend this and add another column for the average over 30 days.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive I understand your question, but I believe you're trying to `SUM` the Orders column for the previous 7 days and divide by that `COUNT` to get the `AVG`.  If so, then this should work using your supplied Fiddle:

```
declare @DateFrom datetime
    set @DateFrom = '2012-12-01'

    declare @DateTo datetime
    set @DateTo = '2013-03-13'

    ;with orders as (
        select 
        cast(o.ReceivedDate as date) as OrderDate, 
        count(oi.Id) as Orders,
        coalesce(sum(oi.Price), 0) as Price
        from OrderItem oi 
        join [Order] o on oi.OrderId = o.Id
        where cast(o.ReceivedDate as date) >= @DateFrom 
        and cast(o.ReceivedDate as date) <= @DateTo
        group by cast(o.ReceivedDate as date)
    ),
    totals as (
      select c1.OrderDate,
      c1.Price,
      c1.Orders,
      c1.Orders - c2.Orders as DIFF7DAYS, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.OrderDate DESC) rn
      from orders c1
      left join orders c2 on dateadd(day, -7, c1.OrderDate) = c2.OrderDate

  ) 
Select t.OrderDate, t.Price, t.Orders, t.Diff7Days,
  SUM(t2.Orders)/COUNT(t2.Orders) avg
FROM totals t
LEFT JOIN totals t2 on t.rn + 7 > t2.rn and t2.rn >= t.rn
GROUP BY t.OrderDate, t.Price, t.Orders, t.Diff7Days
order by t.OrderDate desc
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b837/67)

If you want NULLs for those records that don't have 7 days worth of data, an easy `CASE` statement to check the `COUNT` can determine that.